# Break in from an else if loop inside a foreach loop in c#

Tags: c#

i have a foreach loop and inside that there is if else loop, in for each loop i am checking the lines of text file , first i check the first line is "ctf" if not exit from all loop, else it is "ctf" then take the next line in the foreach loop and goto else part, but my else part is checking the first line can anybody say what is the actual problem.

```
     bool first = true;int i=0;
       lines = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(),           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
      foreach (string  line in lines)
             {
               if (first)
                {
                    if (line != "CTF") { break; }    // i think the problem is here.
                    first = false;

                }
                else
                {

                    tabs = line.Split('\t');
                    ID = int.Parse(tabs[0]);
                    X = int.Parse(tabs[1]);
                    Y = int.Parse(tabs[2]);
                    H = int.Parse(tabs[3]);
                    W = int.Parse(tabs[4]);
                    Text = tabs[5];
                    ItemTypes types = (ItemTypes)int.Parse(tabs[6]);

                        Items.Add(new FormItem());
                        Items[i].Id = ID;
                        Items[i].X = X;
                        Items[i].Y = Y;
                        Items[i].Height = H;
                        Items[i].Width = W;
                        Items[i].Text = Text;
                        Items[i].Type = types;
                       i++;


                }
```

Comment: The question has already been answered but as general rule, If you have to break out of a loop it's better practice to use a Do While loop instead of Foreach.

Answer (score 1):

Swap the order of the body of the 'if' check

```
        if (first)
            {
                first = false;
                if (line != "CTF") { break; }
            }
```

Your problem is that the bool variable 'first' doesn't get set to false if the first line is not "CTF".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it can be a casing issue consider the following change from...

```
if (line != "CTF") { break; }
```

to...

```
if (string.Compare(line, "CTF", true)== 0) { break; }
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

write first=false after else

```
foreach (string  line in lines)

             {
               if (first)
                {
                    if (line != "CTF") { break; }    // i think the problem is here.

                }
                else
                {

                    tabs = line.Split('\t');
                    ID = int.Parse(tabs[0]);
                    X = int.Parse(tabs[1]);
                    Y = int.Parse(tabs[2]);
                    H = int.Parse(tabs[3]);
                    W = int.Parse(tabs[4]);
                    Text = tabs[5];
                    ItemTypes types = (ItemTypes)int.Parse(tabs[6]);

                        Items.Add(new FormItem());
                        Items[i].Id = ID;
                        Items[i].X = X;
                        Items[i].Y = Y;
                        Items[i].Height = H;
                        Items[i].Width = W;
                        Items[i].Text = Text;
                        Items[i].Type = types;
                       i++;


                }
    first = false;
}
```